# Azure Data Explorer (Kusto) override creationTime

Tags: azure-data-explorer

From the documentation of Azure Data Explorer:

> creationTime: The datetime value (formatted as a ISO8601 string) to use as the creation time of the ingested data extents. If unspecified, the current value (now()) will be used. Overriding the default is useful when ingesting older data, so that retention policy will be applied correctly. For example: with (creationTime="2017-02-13T11:09:36.7992775Z").

How can I see the override value?
Also, how can I override this value using the .net sdk of Kusto?

Answer (score 2):

an extent's `creationTime` is shown as part of the "[.show extents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/extents-commands#show-extents)" command's output, and includes `MaxCreatedOn` and `MinCreatedOn` values - this range is due to the fact extents [may get merged/rebuilt throughout their lifespan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/extents-overview).

`creationTime` is an [ingestion property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/data-ingestion/#ingestion-properties), which needs to be set, if required, when using the .NET client library - the matching class is named `Kusto.Ingest.KustoIngestionProperties` (If you're [ingesting from a query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-from-query), i.e. using a `.set-or-append` command, there's a method named `Kusto.Data.Common.CslCommand.Generator.GenerateTableSetOrAppendCommand()` in the [.NET client library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/api/netfx/about-kusto-data) as well)